# SVN commit/lock/cleanup problem

Tags: svn

I have a little issue using SVN.

When I run `svn stat` I get this:

```
~     some/dir
```

When I run `svn commit -m "test"` I get this:
`svn: working copy '/website' is locked`
`svn: try svn cleanup (cf 'svn help cleanup')`

But when I use cleanup, I have this:
`svn: 'some/dir' is not a working copy directory`

I have some files I would like to keep inside the /website/some/dir directory. How should I proceed?
Thanks for all the help provided.

PS: I'm aware the ~ (tilde) means the directory should be reverted, but I also get the lock problem when I try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe another user added the directory `some/dir` while you were working on it. Now you got the problem that you want to check it in, but you cannot, because the path is already used.

Try checking out `some/dir` into another folder and then commit your changes there.

Comment: I think it's the result of a failed commit, where the directory get locked. I continued to work with it and now it's completely mesed up!

Answer (score 2):

I would abandon this working copy and create a fresh one.  `svn co svn://your.svn.repos/website/some/dir`, put the files in, `svn add` them, and commit.

Comment: Maybe creating a new working copy is the best solution (in terms of rapidity/usability). ^^ I think I'll go with this one.

Comment: This is an annoying error. Sometimes checking out a new working copy seems to be the only solution.